# Android List(RecyclerView Adapter) is changing when Edittext On Text change

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-recyclerview

İ have a problem about RecyclerView filter.
İ am using edittext on text change method for filter text query in recyclerview but when i filter  my Product List is changing.

Note : all of that in fragment and fragment in viewpager.

My problem is that :  when i write something it is working but at the same time my product list's elements are changing to result of filter.

So in example at first
  MyList Has 40 items 
  FilteredDataList is empty
After i write "a" in edittext after that FilteredDataList is has 30 items but MyList has same 30 items. But i have not  set anything to Mylist

**My Data List  ,i get it from sqlite**

```
 productList = new ArrayList<>();
        productList =  handler.getAllProduct();
```

**My  Filter Method**

```
private List<Product> filter(List<Product> models, String query) {
        query = query.toLowerCase();

        List<Product> filteredModelList = new ArrayList<>();

        filteredModelList.clear();
        for (Product model : models) {
            final String text = model.get_ProductName().toLowerCase();
            if (text.contains(query)) {
                filteredModelList.add(model);
            }
        }
        return filteredModelList;
    }
```

**My Edittext OnChange Metod**

```
searchEdt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                  int before, int count) {
            if (s.length() != 0) {
                List<Product> filteredModelList = filter( productList, s.toString());

                rcAdapter.animateTo(filteredModelList);
                pager_recycler_view.scrollToPosition(0);
            } else {

                rcAdapter.animateTo(productList);
                pager_recycler_view.scrollToPosition(0);
            }
        }
    });
```

**My AdapterClass**

```
 public class ProductRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter< ProductRecyclerViewHolder > {

        private List<Product> itemList;
        private Context context;

        public ProductRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<Product> itemList) {
            this.itemList = itemList;
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public ProductRecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.product_card_single_item, null);
            ProductRecyclerViewHolder rcv = new ProductRecyclerViewHolder(layoutView);
            return rcv;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ProductRecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {


            holder.productName.setText(itemList.get(position).get_ProductName());
            holder.productWatCode.setText("%" +itemList.get(position).get_ProductWatCode());
            holder.productPOR.setText("%" +itemList.get(position).get_ProductPOR());
            holder.productRSP.setText("£" +itemList.get(position).get_ProductRSP());
            holder.productDescription.setText(itemList.get(position).get_ProductDescription());
            holder.productSKU.setText(itemList.get(position).get_ProductSKU());
            holder.productPrice.setText("£" + itemList.get(position).get_ProductPrice());
     //       holder.productCountCart.setText("");


            Picasso.with(context)
                    .load( "http://firmabayi.com/images/ilanK/" +itemList.get(position).get_ProductPhoto())
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.add_icon)
                    .error(R.drawable.minus_icon)
                    .into(holder.productPhoto);

           // holder.countryPhoto.setImageResource(itemList.get(position).get_ProductName());

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return this.itemList.size();
        }

        public void animateTo(List<Product> itemList) {
            applyAndAnimateRemovals(itemList);
            applyAndAnimateAdditions(itemList);
            applyAndAnimateMovedItems(itemList);
        }


        private void applyAndAnimateRemovals(List<Product> newModels) {
            for (int i = itemList.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                final Product model = itemList.get(i);
                if (!newModels.contains(model)) {
                    removeItem(i);
                }
            }
        }

        private void applyAndAnimateAdditions(List<Product> newModels) {
            for (int i = 0, count = newModels.size(); i < count; i++) {
                final Product model = newModels.get(i);
                if (!itemList.contains(model)) {
                    addItem(i, model);
                }
            }
        }

        private void applyAndAnimateMovedItems(List<Product> newModels) {
            for (int toPosition = newModels.size() - 1; toPosition >= 0; toPosition--) {
                final Product model = newModels.get(toPosition);
                final int fromPosition = itemList.indexOf(model);
                if (fromPosition >= 0 && fromPosition != toPosition) {
                    moveItem(fromPosition, toPosition);
                }
            }
        }

        public Product removeItem(int position) {
            final Product model = itemList.remove(position);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
            return model;
        }

        public void addItem(int position, Product model) {
            itemList.add(position, model);
            notifyItemInserted(position);
        }

        public void moveItem(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
            final Product model = itemList.remove(fromPosition);
            itemList.add(toPosition, model);
            notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
        }

    }
```

Comment: could you please also post your adapter code ?

Comment: I added adapter class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i solved my problem it is only about adapter class one line :(

**in adapter class**

instead of

```
this.itemList = itemList;
```

use that

```
this.itemList = new ArrayList<>(itemList);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is about your productList.
When you create a object like doing this;

```
Class a = b();
```

You are cloning your object. In deep, they are the same object.
So when you filtered object named a, b is being effected from this.

In short, don't do this. Instead of cloning object you should add each items to a from b by one by.
Like this;

```
productList = new ArrayList<>();
    for( int i = 0 ; i <arrayFromSource.size() ; i++ )
    {
        productList.add(arrayFromSource.get(i));
    }
```